# Multi level unique index(Database)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, erd

suppose we have 3 tables (hierarchical)

Table A

```
id, name, ....
```

Table B

```
id, a_id, name
```

Table C

```
id, b_id, name
```

```
table A (id, name, ....)
^
|
table B (id, a_id, name)
^
|
table C (id, b_id, name)
```

I want to make unique Index(a_id, name) on Table C instead of (b_id, name) without redundant and insert a_id in each table How !!!

Comment: An index cannot span two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is in conflict with the design principles for relational databases.

I assume that the index from C to A should reflect the transitive closure of the relationship from C to B and then from B to A. Now, if C contained a link to A by itself, what would happen if a B record b changes its association from a1 to a2? The corresponding C records wouldn't notice this, so in fact the links from them to a1 would have a meaning of their own, not connected to that of b.

So, unless there is a semantic reason to link C to A on its own, and store the link in C, you will have to go from C to be just to find out the current state of B.